# react fetch url changes

Tags: reactjs, url, react-redux, react-router

I get a user profile by ID. But when I try to go to the page of another user using the link from the same page, I can’t catch the new ID from the URL. It is caught in the method componentWillReceiveProps, but I cannot call a database request from it to get data on the ID because an infinite loop occurs.

How can I get a new ID from the /profile/5cc6c0e743d02ff2860d8f20 link so that the component is updated and I can get the data from the database and insert it into the component?

in fact, I need to get the props from props.match.params.id and pass them to this.props.getUserById (this.props.match.params.id), while props.match.params.id is only available in the method componentWillReceiveProps

```
class ProfileUser extends Component {    
    state = {
        user: {}
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // When first time i load component it works fine, i call database and get info
        this.props.getUserById(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // Here I get user information
        this.setState({user: nextProps.profile.user})
        // when I switch to another page with another ID this.props.match.params.id, this method works but I can't call this.props.getUserById(this.props.match.params.id); from here because an infinite loop appears
        // this.props.getUserById(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user)
        return (<div></div>)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only reload the user when the ID changes:

```
if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.props.getUserById(nextProps.props.match.params.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason to get infinite loop**

You get an infinite loop because `componentWillReceiveProps` calls whenever a prop changes, hence under such function if you write that line `this.props.getUserById(this.props.match.params.id)`, it fetches the information of old user (lets say User A) because `this.props` refers to old props while `nextProps` refers to new (lets say user B), hence you again user A. At this moment, the nextProps refer to the user A, while the this.props refer to user B. So, props changes, it again fetches the user B then and you get infinite loop.

**Solution**

Only fetch user if both id's are different and user `nextProps.props.match.params.id` instead of `this.props`.

```
if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.props.getUserById(nextProps.props.match.params.id);
}
```

**Improvements**

I recommended you to use hooks instead of class based components for all the new components you are making. It makes the things more simpler. See the documentation for useEffect hook, you will mention in it arguments that only fetch user if something from user changes. so only one thing will do the job for `componentDidMount` and `ComponentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 1):

You will using ProfileUser Component like this

```
< ProfileUser
{...props}
/>
```

pass `ID` and `KEY` in this component like this

```
< ProfileUser
key={this.props.match.params.id}
id={this.props.match.params.id}
{...props}
/>
```

whenever the key change's the component will be re-render. So, it will start from constructor and you will have new `ID` every-time in props

router will look like this

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/something/:id"
  render={(props)=> (
    <ProfileUser
      key={props.match.params.id}
      id={props.match.params.id}
      {...props}
    />
  )}
/>
```

for addition information on this -- check this link - https://dev.to/ganderzz/react-controlling-rendering-through-keys-274m

Answer (score 0):

1- set id as state variable
2- in component will recieve props check if nextProps.match.params.id is same as id we set in step 1 if yes don't make network call else again setState the id and make network call

Answer (score 0):

Compare, old and new props get user only when the component does anything with 
  new props

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id ) {

        this.props.getUserById(this.props.match.params.id);

      }
```